# Printing tree using GraphViz

Tags: java, graph, tree, graphviz, id3

I have written an ID3 and it prints the data.
Example of output:

```
 if( Outlook == "Sunny") {
    if( Humidity == "High") {
            PlayTennis = "No";
    } else  if( Humidity == "Normal") {
            PlayTennis = "Yes";
    }
} else if( Outlook == "Overcast") {
        PlayTennis = "Yes";
} else if( Outlook == "Rain") {
    if( Wind == "Weak") {
            PlayTennis = "Yes";
    } else  if( Wind == "Strong") {
            PlayTennis = "No";
    }
}
```

I have found that I could use graphviz to get the output graphically, something like below

[image]

However, how can I get a dot file from the output I am getting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create nodes for everything that is connected by arrows (so you need two nodes with the label "No" and three with the label "Yes"). After that, you can make the connections and give them labels as well.